# Selecting rows based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, data.table

I have a df

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(loc.id = rep(1:9, each = 9), month = rep(1:9,times = 9), 
                 x = runif(81, min = 0, max = 5))
```

This is a dataframe which has 9 locations. For each location, I have 9 months and for each month, there is a value of x.

For each location, I want to select a month  based on following criteria:

1) Check which months (excluding month 9) have x > 1 and then select that month which is closest to month 9. 
   For example, if for location 1, values of x is

```
  4.56, 3.41, 0.82, 2.31, 3.75, 4.75, 1.22, 2.98, 1.17
```

then month 1,2,4,5,6,7,8 have x > 1 and from these months, month 8 is closest to month 9. So month 8 will be selected

2) If none of the months have  x > 1, simply select that month which has the highest x value. For example:

If for a location, x is

```
  0.8, 0.6, 0.95, 0.4, 0.88, 0.7, 0.6, 0.45, 0.3
```

then month 3 will be selected (x = 0.95)

I tried this:

```
  library(dplyr)
  df %>% filter(month != 9) %>% # removes the 9 month so that only the 8 months are evaluated 
        group_by(loc.id) %>% 
        mutate(select.month = x > 1) %>% # mark those months where x > 1
        filter(select.month == TRUE) %>% # select those months where x > 1 is true
        mutate(dif = 9 - month) %>%# subtract each month from 9 to check which one is closest to 9
        summarise(month.id = min(dif)) # select the months which is closest to month 9
```

However, in the above function I cannot check for those locations where all the month's have
value less than 1. My question is how do I change the above code to also check condition 2 when none of the x is > 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set.seed(123)
> df <- data.frame(loc.id = rep(1:9, each = 9), month = rep(1:9,times = 9), 
                  x = runif(81, min = 0, max = 5))
> set.seed(123)
> df=rbind(df,cbind(loc.id=10,month=1:9 , x=runif(9)))




> df%>%group_by(loc.id)%>%mutate(x=replace(x,9,0),y=cumsum(x>1))%>%
+     summarise(y=ifelse(all(!y),which.max(x),which.max(y)))
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   loc.id     y
    <dbl> <int>
 1      1     8
 2      2     8
 3      3     8
 4      4     7
 5      5     8
 6      6     8
 7      7     7
 8      8     8
 9      9     7
10     10     5
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified your dataframe a little bit, as there was no case where none of the `loc.id`s had only months with less than 1.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(loc.id) %>%
  filter(month != 9) %>% 
  mutate(all_x_less_1 = all(x < 1)) %>% 
  filter(all_x_less_1 | x > 1) %>% 
  filter(month == if_else(all_x_less_1, month[which.max(x)], month[which.min(9 - month)]))

# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   loc.id [9]
#   loc.id month     x all_x_less_1
#    <int> <int> <dbl> <lgl>       
# 1      1     8 4.46  F           
# 2      2     7 2.25  F           
# 3      3     8 1.18  F           
# 4      4     5 1.13  F           
# 5      5     1 0.758 T           
# 6      6     5 0.715 T           
# 7      7     5 0.639 T           
# 8      8     2 0.509 T           
# 9      9     1 0.395 T
```

The trick is to filter not only on `x < 1`, but also whether all `x` in that `loc.id` are less than 1. Then with the `if_else` call in the `filter` you can specify your criteria based on whether all `x` are less than 1.

**Data**

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(loc.id = rep(1:9, each = 9), month = rep(1:9,times = 9), 
                 x = runif(81, min = 0, max = 5))

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(x = x/loc.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)
d[ , {
  ix <- x > 1 & month != 9 
  .(month = if(any(ix)) last(month[ix]) else month[which.max(x)])
}, by = loc.id]
```

---

Explanation:

For each group (`by = loc.id`), get index where x > 1, excluding month 9 (`x > 1 & month != 9`). If any such index is true (`if(any(ix))`), select the last month among them (`last(month[ix])`). Else select month corresponding to max x (`else month[which.max(x)]`).

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is an `ifelse`, if position 8 is >1.0, then position 8, else max for that row, after excluding row 9.

An example for one month:

`month1 <- filter(df, loc.id == 1)
month1 <- month1[1:8, ]
df1 <- ifelse(month1[8,3] > 1.0, month1[8,3], max(month1$x))`

Comment: Can you write this as a solution. Where would you fit this in my script? Thanks

Comment: Since the OP's example is reproducible, on this site it's usually expected that answers will contain code that works with it.